# Getting arrays of values out of Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

More about getting variables out of `Manipulate`:

If I execute the following:

```
Manipulate[{xb1, xb2, xb3}, 
  {xb1, 0, 1}, 
  {xb2, 0, 1}, 
  {xb3, 0, 1}, 
  LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

I get 3 sliders and the list `{0,0,0}`. If I ask for the value of `xb1`, I get `0`.

If I execute the similar form:

```
Manipulate[{xb[1], xb[2], xb[3]}, 
  {xb[1], 0, 1}, 
  {xb[2], 0,  1}, 
  {xb[3], 0, 1}, 
  LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

I get $3$ sliders and the list `{0,0,0}`. HOWEVER, if I ask for the value of `xb[1]`, I just get `xb[1]`. Why? `LocalizeVariables->False` seems not to work in this case.

More importantly, how can I get a list of the values of the `Manipulate` variables as `Global` variables?

The actual case I'm using has multiple lists of `Locator` variables, which seems to be even more difficult to get at than, say, multiple lists of `Slider` variables.

```
inputgraphs[inputrangex_List, 
            inputrangey_List, 
            name_String, indexnumber_] := 
  DynamicModule[{
    pts = {{0, 0}, {inputrangex[[2]]/4, 0}, {inputrangex[[2]]/2, 0}, 
           {3 inputrangex[[2]]/4, 0}, {inputrangex[[2]], 0}}, 
    locatoricon},
    locatoricon = 
      Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 18];
    Column[{
      LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
        Dynamic[Plot[
          InterpolatingPolynomial[pts, x], {x, 0, inputrangex[[2]]}, 
            PlotRange -> {inputrangex, inputrangey}, Frame -> True, 
            ImageSize -> Medium, Axes -> True, FrameLabel -> name]], 
        Appearance -> locatoricon, LocatorAutoCreate -> True],
      Button["Save", With[{p = pts}, points = p]]}]]
```

I would like to have used the argument `indexnumber` to be an index for each use of manipulate variables (one for each graph), but that doesn't work, probably because for the same reason the example using indexed variables in `Manipulate` given above doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe because `xb[1]` is not a `Symbol` and `LocalizeVariables->False` does not affect it. Just a guess...

Comment: @Kuba is correct. You need to be using symbols. This would also fail for the same reason if you tried `TrackSymbols` for some dynamic operation

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way to capture a list of values in a global variable is to assign that variable directly, e.g.:

```
Manipulate[
  xb = {xb1, xb2, xb3}
, {xb1, 0, 1}
, {xb2, 0, 1}
, {xb3, 0, 1}
]
```

In this example, `xb1`, `xb2` and `xb3` are kept localized to the `Manipulate`, but `xb` is global.

[image: mathematica session screenshot]